# Where is CoverageEye ? Or another free code coverage tool for .Net 

Tags: .net, code-coverage

I was looking for CoverageEye that was available on gotdotnet. But after closing, I'm unable to find it elsewhere.

Do you know more about it ? 
Or another good code coverage tool for .net ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the open source version of [NCover](http://ncover.sourceforge.net/) which is an ealier version of the commercial product.

Another open source alternative is [PartCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/).

I personally use NCover in NAnt for my code coverage reports, which integrates quite nicely with TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at NCover.

http://www.ncover.com/

Comment: ncover is a commercial product.
I'm looking for a free one

Comment: Might want to modify your question to make that clearer then.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) which has been about since 2011.